# data sources and/or softwares to get morphological derivation of words

Tags: grammar, datasets, references, annotated-data

What data sources and/or softwares can generate a list of [morphological derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_derivation) for a given English word?

Comment: Normally the computational problem is stripping them away and finding the lemma behind them all. Doing the reverse would require a [lemmatized](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) wordlist, or an adaptable dictionary. The OED, for instance, will display examples of all variants of a lemma, though each lemma produces several thousand example sentences (there are 2½ million examples in the OED).